# LINQ to SQL submitchanges not doing anything

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

My issue is the following: i'm trying to build a function to which i could pass a list of items, which would then go to the db with each of those items and update them. I believe the issue is within the way datacontexts are being used but i cannot figure out this issue.

Here is my function that builds the list of items that were changed:

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<AFF_CMS_FMA> fmasToSave = new List<AFF_CMS_FMA>();
    AFF_CMS_FMA newFmaItem = new AFF_CMS_FMA();

    foreach (AFF_CMS_FMA fmaItem in FmaLib.fetchAllActiveAssetsInFMA())
    {
        if (fmaItem.SortOrder != Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_SortOrder"]))
        {
            newFmaItem = fmaItem;
            newFmaItem.Name = SecurityLib.SqlSafeString(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_Name"]);
            newFmaItem.AssetID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_AssetID"]);
            newFmaItem.SortOrder = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_SortOrder"]);
            newFmaItem.ImagePathEn = SecurityLib.SqlSafeString(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_ImagePathEn"]);
            newFmaItem.ImagePathCh = SecurityLib.SqlSafeString(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_ImagePathCh"]);
            newFmaItem.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(SecurityLib.SqlSafeString(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_StartDate"]));
            newFmaItem.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(SecurityLib.SqlSafeString(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_EndDate"]));
            newFmaItem.ClickToUrl = SecurityLib.SqlSafeString(Request.Form["fmaItem_" + fmaItem.ID + "_ClickToUrl"]);
            fmasToSave.Add(newFmaItem);

        }
    }
    FmaLib.saveEditedFmas(fmasToSave);
}
```

here is the function that the foreach loops calls to get all the items that are in the db:

```
 public static List<AFF_CMS_FMA> fetchAllActiveAssetsInFMA()
    {
        List<AFF_CMS_FMA> results = null;

        using (fmaDataContext db = new fmaDataContext())
        {
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["fmaActiveList"] == null)
                    {
                        db.LoadOptions = loadAll;
                        results = clsCompiledQuery.getAllActiveFmas(db).ToList();
                        HttpContext.Current.Cache["fmaActiveList"] = results;
                    }
                    else
                        results = (List<AFF_CMS_FMA>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["fmaActiveList"];

                    ts.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { Transaction.Current.Rollback(); }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
```

here are the queries being used:

```
 protected static class clsCompiledQuery
    {
        public static Func<DataContext, IOrderedQueryable<AFF_CMS_FMA>>
        getAllActiveFmas = CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db)
        => from fma in db.GetTable<AFF_CMS_FMA>()
           where fma.IsArchived == false
           orderby fma.SortOrder ascending
           select fma);


        public static Func<DataContext, int,IQueryable<AFF_CMS_FMA>>
        getFmaById = CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db, int ID)
        => from fma in db.GetTable<AFF_CMS_FMA>()
           where fma.ID == ID
           select fma);

    }
```

and finally this were im trying to get the save to happen to the db but no exeptions are throwns, yet the db does not change

```
 public static bool saveEditedFmas(List<AFF_CMS_FMA> fmaToSaveList)
    {
        using (fmaDataContext db = new fmaDataContext())
        {
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (AFF_CMS_FMA fmaItemToSave in fmaToSaveList)
                    {
                        AFF_CMS_FMA fmaItemToUpdate = clsCompiledQuery.getFmaById(db, fmaItemToSave.ID).ToList()[0];
                        fmaItemToUpdate = fmaItemToSave;

                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Transaction.Current.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have checked and the table does contain a primary key in the designer. If i do the save from the btnSave_click function by passing a datacontext to the fetchAllActiveAssetsInFMA() then doing submitchanges on that context it works .. but im trying to abstract that from there.

thanks all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not calling `ts.Complete` in function `saveEditedFmas`.

Also I would recommend calling `db.SubmitChanges();` outside of the for loop. And why do you have a transaction in function `fetchAllActiveAssetsInFMA`? It's only fetching data right? And I'm not quite sure whats happening inside the for loop in save function, looks strange.

I think you should map the properties from `fmaItemToSave` to `fmaItemToUpdate`

```
foreach (var fmaItemToSave in fmaToSaveList)
{
   var fmaItemToUpdate = clsCompiledQuery.getFmaById(db, fmaItemToSave.ID).First();
   fmaItemToUpdate.Name    = fmaItemToSave.Name;
   fmaItemToUpdate.AssetID = fmaItemToSave.AssetID;
   //And the rest of the properties           
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: tried both of those suggestions, nothing. Thanks for the help

Comment: The inside of the for loop in the save function looks strange, your not changing any values of the objects.

Comment: AFF_CMS_FMA fmaItemToUpdate = clsCompiledQuery.getFmaById(db, fmaItemToSave.ID).ToList()[0];
fmaItemToUpdate = fmaItemToSave;  these two lines are setting the object passed in to the equivalent of it on the db . I removed the transaction from fetch you were right about that one . still same result though

Comment: I think you should map the properties from fmaItemToSave to fmaItemToUpdate

Comment: Also dont do `.ToList()[0]` use `.First()` instead, looks better

Comment: You might have to set each property, cause when you set the property the IPropertyChanged (Cant remember the exact name) event gets called and this tells the DataContext which values have changed and hence which values to update.

Comment: the combination of both your answers fixed it !!! i wish i could jump through the screen and hug you !! thanks so much . i needed to map the properties as well as use first for some reason